# Azure AD login using C#. Acquiring Refresh token and Access token

Tags: c#, oauth, azure-active-directory

**Task:** I need to create a WPF application, which will work with EWS(Exchange web-service). I, also, have the 2 restrictions:

- login should proceed only once (it should use refresh token to reconnect)
- it should support 2FA

**My solution part:** I use OAuth to connect to Azure AD. As OAuth client I use Microsoft.Identity.Client. For the first login I have such code:

```
var pcaOptions = new PublicClientApplicationOptions
{
    ClientId = *my_client_id*,
    TenantId = *my_tenant*
};
AuthenticationResult authResult = pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync().Result;
```

This part of code shows up a WPF window, where I input credentials and return me a result(AuthenticationResult), which contains Access Token.

**Problem:** AuthenticationResult doesn't have a Refresh Token, so I can't fulfill the first restriction. Are there any solutions or over ways?

**Additional question:** How to update a Refresh token using Microsoft.Identity.Client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**MSAL.NET does not expose refresh tokens**, for security reasons: MSAL handles refreshing tokens for you with token cache.

> MSAL maintains a token cache and caches a token after it has been acquired. It's also capable of refreshing a token when it's getting close to expiration (as the **token cache also contains a refresh token**).

You can improve the availability of your application by regularly using [**WithForceRefresh**](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/High-availability#pro-active-token-renewal) which will internally acquire new access token when set to `true`

```
result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
             .WithForceRefresh(true)
             .ExecuteAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In case if an account has MFA, and UserTokenCache already has a deserialized information, will the next code works without exception? Is there any expiration of the Refresh Code? And, if yes, what is a lifetime of Refresh token, before it changes?

Comment: By default, access tokens expire after 1h. So it is recommended forcing a refresh every 30 min, or half the lifetime of the AT when this is a custom lifetime. The default  value of refresh token is 90 days, 14 day inactive sliding window .

Comment: What will be happened after Refresh token expires after 90 days (and after 14 days of inactivity)? Is it changes? or it becomes inactive?

Comment: User have to log in again to get new access and refresh token.

Comment: Is there a possibility that Refresh token will be changed during 90 days of current session?

Comment: It is not possible as the  max lifetime for a refresh token is 90 days .