# WithForceRefresh method does not seem to refresh the token

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I am hoping to force refresh my token on a regular basis. i use the following code for that

```
Dim cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create((appID)).WithClientSecret((clientSecret)).WithTenantId((tenantId)).Build()
Dim ewsScopes = New String() {"https://outlook.office365.com/.default"}
authResult = cca.AcquireTokenForClient(ewsScopes).WithForceRefresh(True).ExecuteAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult
```

Still after 65 minutes I get a 401 error and obviously my token has expired.
Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

thanks!
John

use forcerefresh method to renew the token

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to force a refresh for every 30 minutes because Access token expires after the 1 hour.
As said in this SO [Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62577213) by @HariKrishna,

> **MSAL.NET does not expose refresh tokens**, for security reasons: MSAL handles refreshing tokens for you with token cache.

[image]

For the token to be refreshed forcedly, then `WithForceRefresh` method is used which means it will be refreshed for the next time request.
For refreshing the token immediately, you have to call the `AcquireTokenSilent` method along with the parameter `forceRefresh` to `true`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. As this is my first time messing with this I struggle to use the AcquireTokenSilent method. It needs an account as a parameter.
I was hoping to get that as a property from the authresult in de code above but it's not populated.