# Azure B2C + ROPC: User password reset and refresh tokens

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, ropc

I'm working on a Web API (ASP.Net, C#, Entity Framework) and I can't get user password reset and refresh tokens working. I have tried so many things and my boss is getting a bit nervous since I don't have any progress to show.

The important bit is that I have to use the ROPC flow because it is the only flow I can use without any browser-interaction. The goal is to have everything in my own client application, registration, sign-in/out and password reset.

Atm a registered user can sign in via an endpoint of my API. The sign-in code looks like the following:

```
IPublicClientApplication app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_clientId)
                        .WithB2CAuthority(_authority)
                        .Build();

AuthenticationResult result = await app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(_scopesRequiredByAPI,
                                   credentials.Email,
                                   credentials.Pwd).ExecuteAsync();
```

The result object I get in return does not include a refresh token and I don't understand where I can get one.

The other problem I have is password reset. How can a user reset their own password without any browser interaction? Is that not possible with the ROPC flow?

I'm very thankful for tips, suggestions and ideas.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-user-flow):

When using the ROPC flow, consider the following:

ROPC doesn’t work when there's any interruption to the authentication flow that needs user interaction. For example, **when a password has expired or needs to be changed**, multifactor authentication is required, or when more information needs to be collected during sign-in (for example, user consent).

ROPC supports local accounts only. Users can’t sign in with federated identity providers like Microsoft, Google+, Twitter, AD-FS, or Facebook.

Session Management, including keep me signed-in (KMSI), isn't applicable.

It does support refresh tokens. Are you using the offline_access scope?

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply! I suppose that means I have to setup another flow for password resetting that requires browser interaction, right?

And concerning the refresh tokens, I use the following scopes (but I'm not sure if openid and profile make any sense in this context):

"openid", "profile", "offline_access"

I guess I need to construct the correct url to an endpoint to retrieve the refresh token? Or can I do this with the SDK like for the access token?

Comment: As per that link "The tokens returned are an ID token, access token, and a refresh token." So the SDK should work.

Comment: Yes - for reset, use another flow.

Comment: Thanks again! The thing is, the result object of type AuthenticationResult does not have a refresh token property and thus I wouldn't know how to get the refresh token. It seems like it won't be that easy with ROPC :(

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62560052/azure-ad-login-using-c-acquiring-refresh-token-and-access-token